# How to re-enable SSLv3 in Tomcat 8 and Java 8

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, sslv3

Using embedded Tomcat 8 with Java 8 and I am unable to get the SSLv3 protocol re-enabled. I am unable to hit the web application with Internet Options -> Advanced settings with SSLv3 checked and all others (SSLv2, TLS1.0, TLS1.1, TLS1.2) unchecked. I have tried setting the SSL protocol like so:

```
httpsConnector.setAttribute("sslProtocol", "SSLv3");
```

I have also tried setting the SSL protocol like so:

```
httpsConnector.setAttribute("sslEnabledProtocols", "SSLv3");
```

I have also added this line to the deployment.properties file to enable SSLv3 in JRE 8

```
deployment.security.SSLv3=true
```

Comment: See [Enabling SSLv3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#enable-sslv3).

Comment: See [Don't ever enable SSLv3 again](http://disablessl3.com/). SSLv3 is vulnerable to *POODLE* attacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recent JREs disable SSLv3, and rightly so: it's a broken protocol at this point that should be avoided. However, some environments absolutely require support of SSLv3, and it is possible to do.

First, you should never disable the higher-level protocols like TLSv1, TLSv1.1, and TLSv1.2. Instead, add SSLv3 to those protocols so that clients with better security can still use the higher-level protocols.

In order to re-enable SSLv3 in the JVM, you'll need to set this system property, possibly at JVM launch-time:

```
-Djdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=
```

(Note there is no value there.)

You will also need to do the same type of thing you have done already above, where you set `sslEnabledProtocols` and `sslProtocol`, but, again, *please don't disable the higher-level protocols*.

***UPDATE 2017-06-21***

For Tomcat 8.5 and 9.0, `SSLv3` has been hard-coded to be disabled and requires a source patch and re-build in order to re-enable it, up through at least Tomcat 8.5.15 and Tomcat 9.0.0.M21. There is currently some discussion about removing that prohibition in Tomcat 8.5 and 9.0.

***UPDATE 2017-06-22***

`SSLv3` will no longer be blacklisted as of [Tomcat 8.5.17 and Tomcat 9.0.0.MR23](http://markmail.org/message/k4aed2xigmkp53uz).

Comment: Was able to use your solution as a starting point to get this to work. 1. update java.security file
2. update user level deployment.properties file
3. update system level deployment.properties file

Comment: None of those things should have been necessary; you can launch a single JVM instance with those settings without modifying any of the system-level files. I would encourage you to undo what you have done to those system files, because you will be re-enabling SSLv3 for any JVM you launch, not just the single Tomcat instance you want to modify.

Comment: And you will also lose those modifications next Java upgrade.